# Find edges of images

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, numpy, image-processing

I have software that generates several images like the following four images:

[image: image 01]

[image: image 02]

[image: image 03]

[image: image 04]

Does an algorithm exist that detects the (horizontal & vertical) edges and creates a binary output like this?

[image]

If possible I'd like to implement this with `numpy` and `scipy`. I already tried to implement an algorithm, but I failed because I didn't find a place to start. I also tried to use a neural network to do this, but this seems to be overpowered and does not work perfectly.

Comment: I recommend using opencv or scikit-image which are much more suited compared to numpy/scipy (the latter are internal dependencies of scikit-image)

Comment: Hough transform and some prior cleanup should work fine. why are some areas so blurred?

Comment: I think you've got some water in your program

Comment: Thanks, i just started to playing around with http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.hough_line . Do you have some good ideas for prior cleanup? I try to do it with sharpening. The images are blurred, because they are an output of a neural network which should show where are borders between some areas of interest. Unfortunately sometimes the lines are blurred (the border of the areas is not always 100% clean in the input), which is exactly the reason why i try to "interpolate" the output to nice looking lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to try is to:

- Convert your images to binary images (by a simple threshold)
- Apply the Hough transform (OpenCV, Matlab have it already implemented)
- In the Hough transform results, detect the peaks for angles 0 degree, + and - 90 degrees. (Vertical and horizontal lines)

In OpenCV and Matlab, you have extra options for the Hough transform which allow you to fill the gaps between two disconnected segments belonging to a same straight line. You may need a few extra operations for post-processing your results but the main steps should be these ones.